# Get url to mozilla sidebar with javascript

Tags: javascript, url, firefox-addon-sdk, mozilla, firefox-sidebar

I'm trying to develop a mozilla sidebar.
I would like to send the url of the current webpage to my sidebar so i can do something with it.

I've tried with window.location.hostname and other stuff and the only thing i get is the location of my sidebar. Something like this:
`jid1-r7ctykgwy6iyza-at-jetpack`

## EDIT: i would like to have a button to make bookmarks in my sidebar

Could somebody please help me with that?
thanks

Comment: is your sidebar in a separate iframe?

Comment: Yes, my sidebar is a mozilla extension (.xpi) so it's in a separate frame but integrated in my browser.

Comment: Check if this works `var currentUrl = document.referrer;`

Comment: I did, and it doesn't give me any output now

Comment: Don't know if it makes any difference but i'm checking it with  "cfx run"

Comment: #EDIT : i would like to make a sidebar with a button to make bookmarks

Comment: @MaxZoom do you know how to do this?

Comment: According to the [API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/url) your original solution should work. Check for any syntax missing there.

Answer (score 0):

The firefox sidebar is limited to displaying local pages only.  You'll have to create an html page to display in the sidebar, then use messaging from your addin to alter that html pages's contents.